# how to repeat different element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

suppose there is an array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want first element repeat 3 times, the rest elements repeat 2 times.

at the end I want to have something like this 
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]

I know that we can write a dummy loop. But is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Use reduce. It's one of my favorite for this type of thing

Comment: There are many, many ways to do that in javascript.   Depends on what you mean by `better`.  Some people think "shorter" or "less typing" means better, and I tend to disagree.  I find that most of the time "more readable" or "more understandable" is better; and sometimes "faster" is better, and sometimes "less memory" or "portability" is better.  That said, I'd wager the "dummy loop" would be the easiest for someone else to read, and the most portable.  I'm sure there are other ways that are faster or use less memory, though, if that is a concern.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `flatMap()`. Create array of length `2` or `3` based of index and `fill()` it with element.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let res = arr.flatMap((x,i) => Array(i === 0 ? 3 : 2).fill(x))

console.log(res)
```

For more general solution create a function which takes three parameters.

```
const createArray = (arr,times,obj) => arr.flatMap((x,i) => Array(obj[i] || times).fill(x))
```

> **arr**: Given array whose values will be repeated.
>   **times**: No of times every element will be repeated.
>   **obj**: An object which have keys as index and value no of times the element at that index will repeat.

```js
const createArray = (arr,times,obj) => arr.flatMap((x,i) => Array(obj[i] || times).fill(x))

let arr = [1,2,3,4];
const obj = {0:5,3:3}
let res = createArray(arr,2,obj); 
//1 will be repeated 5 times. 4 will be repeated 3 times and all others two tiems
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Instead of `[x,x].concat(i === 0 ? x : [])`, you can also do `Array(i === 0 ? 3 : 2).fill(x)`. Not sure which is better.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` and check the index, then use spreading:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
  acc.push(curr, curr);
  if (idx == 0) acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Ok @Ry-, I'll fix that.